# How to receive udp-GELF message in gzip format via akka stream

Tags: scala, udp, akka-stream, gzipstream, gelf

I'm trying to write a program which listens to the specific port which another program send fake GELF message in UDP and gzips format on that. when the GELF message isn't gzipped It's easy to work with that, but when It's gzipped I don't know what to do. my code and error are :

```
class ListenUdp(remote: InetSocketAddress) extends ActorPublisher[GelfMessage] with ActorLogging {

  import context.system

  IO(Udp) ! Udp.Bind(self, remote)

  def receive: Receive = {
    case Udp.Bound(local) =>
    log.info(s"############ local: $local")
    context.become(ready(sender()))
  }

  def ready(socket: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case Udp.Received(data, _) =>
      convertToGelf(data.decodeString("UTF-8")) match {
    case Success(message) => onNext(message)
    case Failure(ex0) => ex0.printStackTrace()
  }

  case Udp.Unbind => socket ! Udp.Unbind
  case Udp.Unbound => context.stop(self)

  }
}
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
>   ��8�TE����D�xP����ϕ���8�3��nn+����oRֲ+4ĥR�Byn��|>j��c  �+4$�9cV�
>   �E7v�A�����_@Aq�磺pk�AȾ_8������\�I�ႌ�ɬq���Q���t��ɰEB����s�;��%�[[nGh}�F0Cs�(�I0��  ���>��  ; line: 1, column: 2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._throwInvalidSpace(ParserMinimalBase.java:509)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2364)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:644)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3834)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3756)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2099)
>       at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(JacksonJson.scala:234)
>       at play.api.libs.json.StaticBinding$.parseJsValue(StaticBinding.scala:15)
>       at play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(Json.scala:168)
>       at io.skul.ListenUdp$$anonfun$io$skul$ListenUdp$$convertToGelf$1.apply(ListenUdp.scala:48)
>       at io.skul.ListenUdp$$anonfun$io$skul$ListenUdp$$convertToGelf$1.apply(ListenUdp.scala:46)
>       at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>       at io.skul.ListenUdp.io$skul$ListenUdp$$convertToGelf(ListenUdp.scala:46)
>       at io.skul.ListenUdp$$anonfun$ready$1.applyOrElse(ListenUdp.scala:36)
>       at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:484)
>       at io.skul.ListenUdp.akka$stream$actor$ActorPublisher$$super$aroundReceive(ListenUdp.scala:22)
>       at akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisher$class.aroundReceive(ActorPublisher.scala:325)
>       at io.skul.ListenUdp.aroundReceive(ListenUdp.scala:22)
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>       at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

How can I handle this ?

Comment: I had this problem too, you find anything?